# HTML to PDF Generation in Scala Language

Tags: scala, pdf-conversion

I have already done Pdf generation from HTML in JAVA and it worked fine.
But I need this to be done with "scala". Even though I import all the jars as did in JAVA there comes a problem with IText Renderer.
Please suggest me the same to achieve the output.

**Java Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;

public class Htmltopdf_hcue {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        String File_To_Convert = "F:/Pdf_Generation/Appointment Schedule_Fair_Edit.html";
        //String File_To_Convert = "C:/Users/hCue/Desktop/img.html";        
        String url = new File(File_To_Convert).toURI().toURL().toString();
        System.out.println(""+url);
        String HTML_TO_PDF = "F:/Pdf_Generation/TheEndPDF344444444444.pdf";
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(HTML_TO_PDF);
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocument(url);      
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(os);        
        os.close();
    }   
}
```

**Scala Code :**

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import java.io.File

import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.net.URL
import javax.imageio.ImageIO
import java.io
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextTextRenderer
object Hello{
    def main(args: Array[String]) { 
    var fos: FileOutputStream = null
    val File_To_Convert  ="F:/Pdf_Generation/Appointment Schedule_Fair_Edit.html";
    val url = new File(File_To_Convert).toURI().toURL().toString();
    val HTML_TO_PDF = "F:/Pdf_Generation/TheEndPDF344444444444.pdf";
    fos = new FileOutputStream(HTML_TO_PDF);
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();/*Getting Error as Value renderer is not a member object of org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer */
        renderer.setDocument(url);      
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(fos);  
        fos.close();

    } 

}
```

**Build.sbt**

```
//resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
// The Typesafe repository
//resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
// The Play plugin
//addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.7")
// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % Option(System.getProperty("play.version")).getOrElse("2.3.1"))
// web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.github.play2war" % "play2-war-plugin" % "1.3-beta1")
```

Thank you in advance..!

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer(); /*value renderer is not a member of object org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer*/
renderer.setDocument(url);     /* not found value renderer*/ 
renderer.layout();  /* not found value renderer*/
renderer.createPDF(os); /* not found value renderer*/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define render as `val`

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import java.io.File

import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.net.URL
import javax.imageio.ImageIO
import java.io
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer

object Hello{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var fos: FileOutputStream = null
    val File_To_Convert  ="F:/Pdf_Generation/Appointment Schedule_Fair_Edit.html"
    val url = new File(File_To_Convert).toURI().toURL().toString()
    val HTML_TO_PDF = "F:/Pdf_Generation/TheEndPDF344444444444.pdf"
    fos = new FileOutputStream(HTML_TO_PDF)
    val renderer = new ITextRenderer()
    renderer.setDocument(url)
    renderer.layout()
    renderer.createPDF(fos)
    fos.close()

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank You so much @FaigB. It really worked for me..!

Comment: Hi @FaigB,  For the standalone programs it works fine, But I actually have the scala project. But when i am compiling the whole project. I am getting the following error :

Comment: [error] F:\WorkSpacescala\helper\hcueDocuments.scala:37: object lowagie is not a member of package com
[error] import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
[error]            ^
[error] F:\WorkSpace\scala\helper\hcueDocuments.scala:38: object xhtmlrenderer is not a member of package org
[error] import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;
[error]            ^
[error] F:\WorkSpace\scala\helper\hcueDocuments.scala:102: not found: type ITextRenderer
[error]         var renderer =new ITextRenderer()
[error]             ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed

Comment: Already imported the required jars to in the project..! What will be the possibility of this issue..?

Comment: how looks like your build.sbt ?

Comment: I have not did any changes in build.sbt regarding itext. It Seems that need to add something to build.sbt. Can you please help me out in framing that in build.sbt..? I will attach my build.sbt in the question for your reference

Comment: there should be libraryDependencies += "com.lowagie" % "itext" % "2.1.7"

Comment: for org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf I am not sure which version will be suitable

Comment: Thank you.. @FaigB Now it shows error only for this org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf. I am using the following jars for that  1. xhtmlrenderer-1.0.0-sources.jar  2.iText-2.0.8.jar 3.core-renderer.jar . Can you please frame same for that and it will be helpful if you explain what it means for "libraryDependencies += "com.lowagie" % "itext" % "2.1.7"" and how it works..?

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xhtmlrenderer/core-renderer pick up version of library click sbt tab there and copy paste libarydependecy

Comment: Yeah I done it..! You are really helpful and prompt responder. Well Done..!@FaigB.